# Hosting Disabled 'load data local infile' any alternative for loading CSV remotely without phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin, load-data-infile

I'm trying to load massive CSV files, via command line, into a shared hosting MySQL account but they've disabled 'load data local infile'.
I get this error:

```
ERROR 1148 (42000) at line 115: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

Here's an excerpt of the script I'm using:

```
CREATE TABLE bk
( 
  Borough CHAR(2),
  Block DECIMAL(5),
  Lot DECIMAL(4),
);

load data local infile 'BK.csv' into table pluto_BK fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' escaped by '\\' lines terminated by '\n' starting by '' ignore 1 rows
(@vBorough, @vBlock, @vLot)
SET
Borough = nullif(@vBorough,''),
Block   = nullif(@vBlock,''),
Lot = nullif(@vLot,'');
```

Any way around this? Or how can I declare the rules in the last part starting from SET while using phpMyAdmin import?

Comment: If you can find any way to import your data, then you could do that followed by an update.

Comment: I've managed to split then import the CSVs, what now?

Comment: Do you have update rights on this table?

Comment: yes I'm the admin

Comment: I just want to update the  *  Borough = nullif(@vBorough,'')  * part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround would be to just import your data any way possible and then do the following update:

```
UPDATE bk
SET
    Borough = COALESCE(Borough, ''),
    Block   = COALESCE(Block, 0.0),
    Lot     = COALESCE(Lot, 0.0);
```

Note that in this particular case, since you want to replace `NULL` (i.e. unassigned) values you could have also specified default values in your table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE bk (
    Borough CHAR(2) DEFAULT '',
    Block DECIMAL(5) DEFAULT 0.0,
    Lot DECIMAL(4) DEFAULT 0.0
);
```

Comment: oooh it just set all the fields to null, even those that were populated

Comment: No, that doesn't sound right.  Are you sure you really imported your data correctly?

Comment: I created the table using 1st portion, then manually imported CSV, then ran UPDATE... phpMyAdmin uses wraps fields with ` I didn't

Comment: This seems like a totally unrelated follow up question.  Maybe you should ask a new question.  Wait...are you asking for a default date value?

Comment: yea. I see ur using ' ' for CHAR and 0.0 for DECIMAL

Comment: I think it really depends on whether it makes logical sense to have a hard coded default date value.  I would rather just allow `null` to serve as the default date value.